# How do I make inno setup pull local ip address?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the local IP Address using Inno-setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166900/how-to-get-the-local-ip-address-using-inno-setup)

I couldn't find anyway to pull local ip address to display in a text field for installer. I think what I need is IPv4. I wonder if inno have a way to pull these values like some of its constant values? Please help.

Comment: You didn't do enough searching. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166900/how-to-get-the-local-ip-address-using-inno-setup) question.

Comment: I did see that, but some how when I run the code it doesn't work out. It gave me blank result. And I am not sure how to use DLL either.

Comment: If you've already looked at questions on SO and they didn't help you, perhaps you should specify that in your question.