# Is it possible to get IP address in setup?

Tags: inno-setup, setup-deployment

Is anyway there I can able to get IP address of the system where I am installing my setup application using INNOSETUP?

Comment: You can have more than one IP address assigned...

Comment: Why do you need the IP address during the installation?

Comment: You could take a look at [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166900/how-to-get-the-local-ip-address-using-inno-setup)

Comment: @RobeN I tried that solution which you given but when tries to execute it's showing error saying unknow tag WordBool .

Comment: @reapen - that means you are probably modified the code (or maybe you use ANSI version of Inno Setup?). When I use 1:1 I get MsgBox non the Initialize with my IPs listed.

Comment: @RobeN I not modified the code.i am using Inno Setup Compiler version 5.5.3.is this version you also using? is so can you give an example for that?

Comment: @reapen - I'm also usin 5.5.3. However I use Unicode version - what may be important.

Comment: @RobeN: actually i want is to get IP address of users who will be installing our application through innosetup.as there is one requirement for saving user's ip in database.So it's will be great help to know while executing the application we can able to capture the IP address of user.

Comment: If you want to capture one or more of the IPs of each user who runs your application, then that sounds like something you'd do in your application, not the installer.  After all, a given computer may have several IPs and they may change over time.  (TBH I don't see what possible use this sort of thing would be, given that.)

Comment: Anyways, that script captures IP addresses of the computer which runs the installer/setup. So in fact you can do with received data anything you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function:

```
Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/C ipconfig | findstr "IPv4"', '', 0,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

you will get IP address of the system

Windows:

```
C:\Users\LEo>ipconfig | findstr "IPv4"
IPv4 addr . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.101
IPv4 addr . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.82
```

Comment: Sorry, this function can only get the return value（ResultCode）.you can not get ip ：）

Comment: Avoid using command line tools as much as you can. Always prefer native Windows API solutions. In this question is the term IP of system pretty vague and as you can see in your listing, on your system you got two different IPs.

Comment: thks for your suggestion, so I can not get the IP, .:( I will try it.