# How to get external (public) IP in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ip, external

I need to get my external (public) IP address from Delphi.

The same IP that is shown by [www.whatismyip.com](https://www.whatismyip.com) for example.

How can I do that ?  Winsock doesn't allow this.

Comment: By external IP address, do you mean your internet accessible IP address?  Or do you mean a local network address that is not 127.0.0.1?

Comment: internet accessible address, the same that is shown by www.whatismyip.com

Comment: This question shows your computer's actual IP addresses; 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576538/delphi-how-to-get-all-local-ips

Comment: This is not possible in general case, ask about your specific problem.

Comment: Who says you only have one? Anyway, Downvoter* has a point that you need to sketch your problem more. What do you think you need the external IP  for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can. Well, you could call some service that tells you what your IP address appears to be, ( ex: http://www.whatismyip.com/ ) and figure it out from the response.  But I don't think anything on your PC will be able to tell you what your IP address looks like, to the outside world.

Untested, but I think you can do this with Indy:

```
MyPublicIP := IdHTTP1.Get('http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp');
```

Please review the rules/policy at: http://www.whatismyip.com/faq/automation.asp before using this.

Comment: ... and the reason is that your public address is not necessarily attached to your computer. Pretty often, it's assigned to an external router, which is an entirely different computer to all effects.

Comment: Yes. Public IP and adapter with default gateway are two different things.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this website: http://ipinfo.io/json. It returns the information about your current internet connection in `JSON` format.

In delphi you need use `IdHTTP` this way: `IdHTTP1.Get('http://ipinfo.io/json')`
and it will returns a string with all the data. You can use a `JSON`interpreter you like or you can use the `lkJSON` as the following example:

```
json := TlkJSON.ParseText(MainEstrutura.IdHTTP1.Get('http://ipinfo.io/json')) as TlkJSONobject;

str := json.Field['ip'].Value;
```

I hope help you.

Comment: If you use `http://ipinfo.io/ip` instead, it returns just the IP by itself in plain text without wrapping it in JSON that has to be parsed.

Comment: As the code in this answer you need use: `http://ipinfo.io/json` to get all information about this IP

Comment: The OP did not ask to retrieve all the details about the IP, only to retrieve the IP itself. So `/json` is overkill when `/ip` will suffice. If you read the website's documentation, individual fields can be retrieved by themselves.

Answer (score 6):

this works for me:

```
  uses JSON,IdHTTP;
  function GetIP():String;
  var  LJsonObj   : TJSONObject;
  str:string;
  http : TIdHttp;
  begin
    str:='';
    http:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
        str:=http.Get('http://ipinfo.io/json');
        LJsonObj:= TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str),0)           as TJSONObject;
        str := LJsonObj.Get('ip').JsonValue.Value;
        LJsonObj.Free;
        http.Free;
    Except
    end;
    result:=str;
end;
```

Comment: I prefer to use services that report the IP by itself as plain text without any extra metadata formatting. For example: `function GetIP: String; begin with TIdHTTP.Create do try Result := http.Get('http://ipinfo.io/ip'); finally Free; end; end;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau The best and simple solution ! (but replace `http.Get` with `Get`)

Answer (score 2):

From memory, untested:

```
function GetMyHostAddress: string;
var
   http: IWinHttpRequest;
begin
   http := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest5.1') as IWinHttpRequest;
   http.Open('GET', 'http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp', False);
   http.Send(EmptyParam);

   if http.StatusCode = 200 then
      Result := http.ResponseText
   else
      Result := '';
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function GetMyIP:string;
var
  xmlhttp:olevariant;
  s,p:integer;
  temp:string;
begin
  result:=emptystr;
  xmlhttp:=CreateOleObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  try
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://www.findipinfo.com/', false);
    xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3');
    xmlhttp.send(null);
  except
    exit;
  end;
  if(xmlhttp.status = 200) then
  temp:=trim(VarToStr(xmlhttp.responseText));
  xmlhttp:=Unassigned;
  s:=pos('Address Is:',temp);
  if s>0 then
  inc(s,11)
  else
  exit;
  temp:=copy(temp,s,30);
  s:=pos('<',temp);
  if s=0 then exit
  else
  dec(s);
  result:=trim(copy(temp,1,s));
end;
```