# How can I retrieve the GUID's for the network adapters on my system?

Tags: delphi

I wrote a simple tool that emulates the *nix "ifconfig -a" in Delphi and [posted it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325872/detect-an-internet-connection-activation-with-delphi/331421#331421) on SO. However, I would also like to be able to retrieve the adapter's GUID as well. Is there a way to do this in Delphi, without using WMI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check this windows registry key

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> Microsoft -> WindowsNT -> CurrentVersion- > NetworkCards 
undear each number see the value of the `ServiceName` this is the GUID

[image]